# Ola Hallengrens code for Index Optimization - Clarifications

Tags: index, sql-server-2014, ola-hallengren

I am trying to deploy Ola Hallengrens code for Index Optimization in our PROD environment.

What is the difference between using **USER_DATABASES** and **AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES** in the place of @Databases in below code .

Also I was going through the blogs and read :

Ola Hallengrens code for Index Optimization is meant to defragment only with page count more than 1000.

When I execute below command it updates only statistics not rebuild indexes -

Does this mean I am good with fragmentation , not to worry much about it as my end users does not complaint any thing about slow response or bad performance from Database end .

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
 @Databases = '',
 @FragmentationLow = NULL,
 @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
 @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
 @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
 @FragmentationLevel2 = 30
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between **user_databases** & **availability_group_databases** is that when specifying user_databases you will optimize **every** user database (also the ones in the AG group) if you specify **availability_group_databases** you will **only** optimize the indexes of databases inside an availability group.

If you do not have tables with fragmentation above 1000 pages, this will not hurt your SQL Server performance. I recommend you also read this post from Brent Ozar. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/

Comment: +1 For the simple explanation. And yes you can change the script anytime if your want action for lesser page count @PageCountLevel int = 500, in theIndexOptimize SP.

Answer (score 1):

### Availability Group Databases

If you have a quick look at the documentation there is a nice example for the `USER_DATABASES` and `AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES`:

> #### Databases
>
> Select databases. The keywords SYSTEM_DATABASES, USER_DATABASES, ALL_DATABASES, and AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES are supported. The hyphen character (-) is used to exclude databases, and the percent character (%) is used for wildcard selection. All of these operations can be combined by using the comma (,).
>
> ```
> Value                                           Description  
> ----------------------------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------  
> SYSTEM_DATABASES                                All system databases (master, msdb, and model)  
> USER_DATABASES                                  All user databases`  
> ALL_DATABASES                                   All databases`  
> AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES                    All databases in availability groups  
> USER_DATABASES, -AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES   All user databases that are not in availability groups  
> Db1                                             The database Db1  
> Db1, Db2                                        The databases Db1 and Db2  
> USER_DATABASES, -Db1                            All user databases, except Db1  
> `%Db%                                           All databases that have “Db” in the name  
> %Db%, -Db1                                      All databases that have “Db” in the name, except Db1  
> ALL_DATABASES, -%Db%                            All databases that do not have “Db” in the name
> ```

### Index Fragmentation

As you correctly noted, index optimisation is triggered at certain levels.

- An index is reorganised if there are more than 1000 pages in the table and index fragmentation is between 5 and 30 percent.
- An index is rebuilt if there are more than 1000 pages in the table and index fragmentation is above 30 percent.

Depending on your requirements and/or the size of the data, you might have to reorganise some indexes earlier.

#### Very simple example

You have a table with 200 Million records (online archive) and 10'000 records are modified on a daily basis and 10'000 records are created daily. Doing the simple maths results in a maximum fragmentation of 0.01% which will never trigger the index reorg or rebuild. It would take 500 days to reach 5% fragmentation. In a production environment this could lead to potential performance issues, depending on the size of the table involved and the complexity of the queries.

#### Your question answered

Yes, you are good for fragmentation, with the above limitations.